# how to run GitHub Action after outage?

Tags: github, github-actions

As you may (or may not) know yesterday was a major incident of GitHub's services: https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/tyc8wpsgr2r8.

Unfortunately I published a release during that time and the action responsible for building and publishing the code didn't trigger.

For actions which were executed at least once I have an option to "Re-run workflow" - but how can I proceed with an action which didn't even trigger - I can not see it anywhere whatsoever?

I think the last resort would be to just make another release, remove the problematic one etc. but I'd like to avoid that.

The workflow file:

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  release:
    types: [published]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
jobs:
  test:
    name: Test Node.js v${{ matrix.node-version }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version:
          - 16
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm install --production=false --no-package-lock
      - name: Lint 
        run: npm run lint
      - run: npm test
  release:
    name: Publish NPM Package
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
    needs:
      - test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
      - run: npm install --production=false --no-package-lock
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
  gh-pages:
    name: Publish GitHub Pages
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}
    needs:
      - test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    continue-on-error: true
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
      - name: Install ✔️
        run: npm install --production=false --no-package-lock
      - name: Build storybook ️
        run: npm run build-storybook
      - name: Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.3
        with:
          branch: gh-pages
          folder: storybook-static
```

Comment: Okay, I ended up removing and creating the release over again, but I'll accept any Answer which will explain how to trigger the "release published" event.

Comment: What was your workflow trigger event, could you share the implementation (at least this part)?

Comment: @GuiFalourd there you go, you think it's related to the trigger failure? Because it's just as I wrote: I only had to remove the previous release and publish the release once again and the action get triggered. But It would much easier if I could artificially trigger "release_published" event just like I can trigger the "workflow_dispatch" event with the `gh` cli tool: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow

Comment: What I would do in that case, is adding a `workflow_dispatch` event to the workflow with an input `tag`, updating the jobs condition to use this `input.tag` if informed. That way, if an automatic trigger failed (through push, release or pull_request), you could trigger it manually through the Github UI or the GH CLI.

Comment: @GuiFalourd awesome idea, I didn't though about that, if you'd add that as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in the comment, the easiest solution would be to remove the release and create it all over again.

Another option could be to add a `workflow_dispatch` event trigger to the workflow with a `tag` input, updating the jobs condition to use this `input.tag` variable if informed.

That way, if an automatic trigger failed (through push, release or pull_request), you could trigger it manually through the **Github UI** or the **GH CLI** as an alternative.